# Why variables are not stored in the process data area in Swift

Tags: swift, memory, struct, process, stack

I know that global variables, static variables, etc. are stored in the Data area of the process memory area.
But, I know that variables of type such as implemented in struct are stored in the stack.

If the variable implemented by the struct is a global variable, can't it be declared in the data area?

I want to know why I can affirm that it is created in the Stack area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Structs are stored on the stack

This is an inaccurate over-simplification.

Structs are stored directly within their "parent", which can be:

1. A heap-allocated object (instance of a `class`, the captured closure context of a closure, etc.)
2. A local variable in a stack frame
3. Or the `Data` segment in the case of a global/static variable

They might not even be stored anywhere as a whole, and have their constituent values only stored in registers, depending on what the optimizer thinks is best.

This is article is about C# (which has GC and JIT), but much of the rest of the ideas apply to Swift as well: https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/

> The way in the past I’ve usually pushed back on this myth is to say that the real statement should be **“in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value.”**

Comment: "...the jitter chooses to not enregister the value, and the wind is blowing from the south southwest?"

Comment: @DuncanC Hmmmm? Are you making a joke about how sensitive/wild optimizers are, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to be funny. (You picked one very specific platform and spelled out all the complexities for that specific platform.)

Comment: Ah, yes! I find it interesting how we collectively try to make it so clear to not depend on the details of what/when optimizations apply, and yet you constantly see questions about people asking why some code complied one way and not another ‍♂️

Comment: BTW, your answer was quite good. (Voted). I was not aware that a JIT compiler was known as a "jitter", so I learned something...